# What files to recreate from .gitignore?

Tags: git, laravel, gitignore

When you clone a repository, what files do you need to recreate so that the app will function?

For example, I committed a laravel app with the standard .gitignore files:

```
### Laravel ###
vendor/
node_modules/
npm-debug.log

# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
storage/*.key
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json

# Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
.rocketeer/
```

Now, if I were to clone this repo. Obviously, this app would not work out of the box. It's missing the important .env and maybe some of the other ignored files.

How do you got about what files to recreate?

Answer (score 0):

Generally we manually create those files on server, Since it's not recommended to keep your `.env` file on Git cause it contains your DB Credentials and other important credentials, plus it helps you to have different environments to have different settings.

Eg. you can have `APP_DEBUG=true` or test/development environments where as on Production it should be false.

And which files to create is decided based on the error we get while setting up.

In Most of the cases you just need to create the `.env` file and give permission to `storage` folder and you are done.

So I would recommend not to remove anything from `.gitignore` file of Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install all dependencies with

```
composer update
```

This will create .env file. In that file fill all fields that you need (e.g DB configs) and run

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```